STM32CubeMX xTaskCreate() not scheduling on STM32F030
I have used STM32CubeMX to create a FreeRTOS task on the STM32F030 development board using the CMSIS-RTOS v2 interface, but the task I created using xTaskCreate() is not scheduling correctly, and the one I created using osTreadNew is working fine，Why is this happening?
I created two tasks using xTaskCreat()
xTaskCreate(
        LibmodbusServerTask,
        "LibmodbusServerTask",
        512,
        NULL,
        osPriorityNormal,
        NULL
    );
xTaskCreate(
        AHT20Task,
        "AHT20Task",
        512,
        NULL,
        osPriorityNormal,
        NULL
    );

There's also a default task
osThreadId_t defaultTaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t defaultTask_attributes = {
  .name = "defaultTask",
  .stack_size = 128 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};
defaultTaskHandle = osThreadNew(StartDefaultTask, NULL, &defaultTask_attributes);

Here's the simplified code for the three tasks
void AHT20Task(void *pvParameters)
{
    while (1)
    {
            //ledTask
            vTaskDelay(100);
    }   
}
void LibmodbusServerTask( void *pvParameters )
{
    //Variables, initialization, connection to modbus
    for (;;) {
        do {
            rc = modbus_receive(ctx, query);
        } while (rc == 0);
        /* The connection is not closed on errors which require on reply such as
           bad CRC in RTU. */
        if (rc == -1 && errno != EMBBADCRC) {
            /* Quit */
            continue;
        }
        rc = modbus_reply(ctx, query, rc, mb_mapping);
        if (rc == -1) {
            //break;
        }

    }
        //close modbus
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
void StartDefaultTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartDefaultTask */
    /* Infinite loop */
    for(;;)
    {   
        vTaskDelay(500);
    }
  /* USER CODE END StartDefaultTask */
}


I'm debugging code on an STM32F030 development board. The code only enters the StartDefaultTask once at startup and then continuously runs the LibmodbusServerTask. The AHT20Task has never been entered.
Next, I simply switched the task creation method and used osThreadNew() to create the task.The program now switches correctly between the LibmodbusServerTask and the AHT20Task.Here is the code to create the task
    osThreadId_t libmodbusTaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t libmodbusTask_attributes = {
  .name = "libmodbusTask",
  .stack_size = 128 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};
  osThreadId_t aht20TaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t aht20Task_attributes = {
  .name = "aht20HandleTask",
  .stack_size = 128 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityNormal,
};
        libmodbusTaskHandle = osThreadNew(LibmodbusServerTask, NULL, &libmodbusTask_attributes);
    aht20TaskHandle = osThreadNew(AHT20Task, NULL, &aht20Task_attributes);

This is part of my STM32CubeMX configuration.
STM32CubeMX configuration
sys timer

Did you also try without the CMSIS_V2 interface? (Select "Disabled" in the drop-down box at the top of your screenshot). If you don't specifically need it, it is just another layer of abstraction that might cause confusion. IMHO the code generation in CubeMX is not great when enabling FreeRTOS and CMSIS. For example xTaskCreate(..., osPriorityNormal, NULL); is wrong: it's mixing the priority levels from CMSIS (of type osPriority) with that of FreeRTOS - they are not the same. I don't think this explains your problem, but it's just easier to stick with one interface (raw FreeRTOS).

To improve this question (and possibly get a more helpful answer), please update your question with a [mre], at least a simple main that can be copy-pasted and tested by others. For example, we don't know how you start the scheduler (e.g. using osKernelStart() or vTaskStartScheduler()) and how you concluded that there's no task switch in the first example (the AHT20Task has no observable behavior, so you could only check it using a debugger, and it's easy to make a mistake and draw the wrong conclusions). See [ask].
